# Generar manifest.json mediante plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugin, wordpress-plugin

Estoy intentando crear un plugin sencillo que genere y cargue el manifest.json de forma dinámica con PHP.
Tengo claro cómo cargar la etiqueta en la cabecera con

```
add_action('wp_header', 'mifuncion')
```

y la función solamente hace

```
echo '<link rel="manifest" href="ruta-al-plugin/manifest.json">';
```

Para hacerlo dinámico llamo a un php en lugar de un json

```
echo '<link rel="manifest" href="ruta-al-plugin/manifest.php">';
```

El archivo manifest.php contiene el siguiente código:

```
<?php
$manifest = array(
    "name"=> "Progress Web App",
    "version"=> "0.3",
    "short_name"=> "PWA"
);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($manifest);
?>
```

He probado lo siguiente con resultado satisfactorio:

- He creado un html y un php que llame a manifest.json ambos en raíz, y lo carga bien.
- He creado un html y un php que llame a manifest.php ambos en raíz, y de forma dinámica me carga bien la información del manifest.

El problema lo tengo cuando lo hago mediante el plugin, que en el código fuente me escribe bien la meta-etiqueta pero no consigo que me carge la información ni en manifest.php ni en manifest.json que hay dentro del plugin.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.